# How do dapp applications have access to your assets belonging in a multisig/smart-contract when they only have access to the wallet address signing?

Tags: multisignature

If I mint an nft that I want myself and another wallet to have access to and I connect to an application that needs access to this minted nft to check the metadata for example how will they be able to do so if the nft is not in my actual wallet but in the multisig smart contract

Comment: Have you read the [Ethereum wallets](https://ethereum.org/en/wallets/) article on the Ethereum website?

Comment: yes did not help out. will reask my question.